# Accessing properties/methods of a Vuejs component globally

Tags: vuejs2

I want to create a custom component  and to use it like

```
<div id="app">
  <router-view />
  <my-custom-loader />
</div>
```

My component has some methods which I want to use globally anywhere like

```
this.$loader.show();
this.$loader.hide();
```

I can create the component but not sure how to inject its method/properties so that it's available everywhere.

Comment: Is this something mixins or plugins could not accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Component create a encapsulated scope in vuejs.

AFAIK  you should not be doing this as I feel this to be more like a workaround that a perfect vuejs way of doing this.

You can setup a ref on the `<my-custom-loader>` component.

```
<div id="app">
    <router-view />
    <my-custom-loader ref="loader"/>
</div>
```

Since the component looks like the child of root vue instance mounted on `#app` you can use it to acess $refs

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});

//my-custom-loader component's instance
var loader = vm.$rers.loader;
```

Then you can setup this `loader` which is the my-custom-loader component's instance on the `Vue.prototype`. This now allows you to acess `$loader` in any component using `this.$loader`

```
Vue.prototype.$loader = loader;
```

Now you can acess its methods using

```
this.$loader.hide();
this.$loader.show();
```

keep in mind the warning of using refs as mentioned in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs)

*`$refs` are only populated after the component has been rendered, and it is not reactive. It is only meant as an escape hatch for direct child manipulation - you should avoid using `$refs` in templates or computed properties.*

As for me I recommend you use [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) or register a global [event bus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) or use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) if your app is very big and has complex state management